# how to update the datasource of a chart in C# panel from another panel

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I'm creating an application consisting of 1 form and several panels, which I stack on top of another panel so I can just call the `panel.BringToFront()`to show it.

My first panel consists of a chart whose datasource is from my database. 
So once I added or changed some data from my second panel, I need to update the chart in the first panel. What I've done is calling `initializeChart()` everytime I add or change something. The problem is my chart in the first panel is not updated. But when i try to update the table inside the same panel it works. Here is my `initializeChart()` code :

```
private void initializeChart()
{               
    chart1.DataSource = database.getMonthlyProfitList();
    chart1.Series["Income"].XValueMember = "Bulan";
    chart1.Series["Income"].YValueMembers = "Pendapatan";
}
```

So do you guys have any Idea why I can update the view on the same panel but not on other panel, and if that's possible how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line of code in the last:

```
private void initializeChart()
{               
    chart1.DataSource = database.getMonthlyProfitList();
    chart1.Series["Income"].XValueMember = "Bulan";
    chart1.Series["Income"].YValueMembers = "Pendapatan";
    chart1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Check this link @VickyS :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.databind(v=vs.110).aspx

Thank you for the down vote. I have used charts a lot.

Comment: thanks @Abhishek it works. can you please explain to me what the DataBind() do? can I also use this on dataGridView?

Comment: The `DataBind()` method will bind the chart to the given data source. It is given in the above link I posted. The same option is not available for `DataGridView`. You just have to set the data source every time which will work. Why the same thing does not work in a chart is because if there are more data operations being performed on the data source, the `DataBind()` method has to be called explicitly.